# How to return data (string) from aggregation without any modifications?

Tags: elasticsearch

Part of my _source looks like this:

```
 "category": {
            "id": 2,
            "translations": [
                {
                    "slug": "word1-and-word2",
                    "language": "en-us",
                    "name": "Word1 & Word2"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Mapping for this part:

```
          category:
                properties:
                    id:
                        type: "long"
                        index: "not_analyzed"
                    translations:
                        properties:
                            name:
                                type: 'string'
                            slug:
                                type: 'string'
                                index: "not_analyzed"
                            language:
                                type: 'string'
                                index: "not_analyzed"
```

I am using aggregation:

```
category:
    terms:
    field: "category.translations.name"
```

However key returned from aggregation is: `word2` instead of `Word1 & Word2`. So it is lowercased and trimmed somehow... How I can return data in intact format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a sub field in your mapping:

```
name: 
   type: 'string'
   fields:
      untouched:
         type: 'string'
         index: 'not_analyzed'
```

Then run the terms aggregation on `category.translations.name.untouched`